# "incompatible types" compiler error with lambda / method referencing and generics

Tags: java, generics, lambda, compiler-errors, method-reference

I stumbled upon an issue when working through some old code, replacing several anonymous classes with either lambda expressions or method references. The problem is a bit hard to explain with words, but I'll do my best, and I've also added a short example illustrating my problem to the best of my abilities below.

My example consists of...

1. A functional interface, **GenericListener**, which takes a **type parameter V** and has a single method "genericCallback(V genericValue)".
2. A class, **CallbackProducer**, which takes a **type parameter T**. This class also has a method to add a GenericListener with type Integer.
3. A **Main** class which creates CallbackProducers and adds GenericListeners to them.

When I run CallbackProducer's addIntegerListener method from Main's constructor, I get the **compiler error: "incompatible types"** whenever i avoid specifying the type of CallbackProducer's T.

The method addIntegerListener only uses GenericListener's V. As far as I know, it doesn't use CallbackProducer's T in any way.

**I've put several calls to addIntegerListener + comments in Main's constructor, 3 of which cause compiler errors**. But as far as I can see (and according to IntelliJ) all of them should be legal. If you comment out the 3 first calls to addIntegerListener the application will compile and run just fine.

Also, if CallbackProducer didn't use generics, and we removed the type parameter T completely, the 3 first calls to addIntegerListener would compile.

Is there a reason for this behavior? Am I misunderstanding something, or is this a weakness or bug in the java compiler? (I'm currently using java 1.8_51)

Thanks in advance for any clarification!

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::new);
    }

    public Main() {

        // Compiler error, type of CallbackProducer's "T" not specified
        CallbackProducer producer1 = new CallbackProducer();
        producer1.addIntegerListener(this::integerReceived);

        // Compiler error, no diamond brackets for CallbackProducer
        new CallbackProducer().addIntegerListener(this::integerReceived);

        // Also compiler error for lambdas with no diamond brackets on CallbackProducer
        new CallbackProducer().addIntegerListener(intValue -> integerReceived(intValue));

        // Works because a (any) type for CallbackProducer's "T" is specified
        CallbackProducer<Object> producer2 = new CallbackProducer<>();
        producer2.addIntegerListener(this::integerReceived);

        // Works because of the diamond brackets
        new CallbackProducer<>().addIntegerListener(this::integerReceived);

        // Lambda also works with diamond brackets
        new CallbackProducer<>().addIntegerListener(intValue -> integerReceived(intValue));

        // This variant also works without specifying CallbackProducer's "T"
        // ... but it is a workaround I'd prefer to avoid if possible :-P
        GenericListener<Integer> integerListener = this::integerReceived;
        new CallbackProducer().addIntegerListener(integerListener);
    }

    private void integerReceived(Integer intValue) {
        System.out.println("Integer callback received: " + intValue);
    }

    // A callback producer taking generic listeners
    // Has a type parameter "T" which is completely unrelated to
    // GenericListener's "V" and not used for anything in this
    // example really, except help provoking the compiler error
    public class CallbackProducer<T> {
        // Adds a listener which specifically takes an Integer type as argument
        public void addIntegerListener(GenericListener<Integer> integerListener) {
            // Just a dummy callback to receive some output
            integerListener.genericCallback(100);
        }
    }

    // A simple, generic listener interface that can take a value of any type
    // Has a type parameter "V" which is used to specify the value type of the callback
    // "V" is completely unrelated to CallbackProducer's "T"
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface GenericListener<V> {
        void genericCallback(V genericValue);
    }
}
```

Here's a shortened down version without all the comment clutter and with only two calls to "addIntegerListener", one of which causes compiler error.

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::new);
    }

    public Main() {

        CallbackProducer producer1 = new CallbackProducer();
        producer1.addIntegerListener(this::integerReceived);    // Compiler error

        CallbackProducer<Object> producer2 = new CallbackProducer<>();
        producer2.addIntegerListener(this::integerReceived);    // Compiles OK      
    }

    private void integerReceived(Integer intValue) {
        System.out.println("Integer callback received: " + intValue);
    }

    public class CallbackProducer<T> {
        public void addIntegerListener(GenericListener<Integer> integerListener) {
            integerListener.genericCallback(100);
        }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface GenericListener<V> {
        void genericCallback(V genericValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 3 compiler errors are due to the fact that you are using a raw `CallbackProducer`.  When you use a raw `CallbackProducer`, all type arguments undergo type erasure, such that any `T`, such as yours, without any upper bound, becomes `Object`.

Because of this, the `addIntegerListener` method expects a raw `GenericListener` as a parameter, something that `integerReceived` no longer fits.  The `integerReceived` method takes an `Integer`, not an `Object`, as a raw `GenericListener` would supply.

You must supply the angle brackets `<>` on `CallbackProducer` to avoid using raw types, as you've done on your subsequent examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you say may for all i know very well be the reason the compiler complains, but CallbackProducer's <T> is never used. "addIntegerListener" already specifically takes a GenericListener<Integer> as argument. Also, the following lines compiles and runs just fine:  
  
`CallbackProducer<Double> producer2 = new CallbackProducer<>();
producer2.addIntegerListener(this::integerReceived);`  
  
Now I'm saying T is a Double, when I'm working with integer listeners. It still works, since T is unrelated to the listener.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what the type argument to `CallProducer` is.  It has everything to do with the fact that you've used a raw `CallProducer`.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: What you are saying is that if I use a raw CallbackProducer (or any other class that takes a type parameter), all other type arguments in that producer get type erased, even if they are completely unrelated to the CallbackProducer's "T"? (like in my case) I don't doubt you're right, but out of curiosity, is there a reason for this behavior? I can't see why this should be a problem. The types are guaranteed to match. Do you know if this is a weakness in the compiler that may be addressed in the future or if this is by design?

Comment: Yes, all other type arguments are erased, even unrelated ones such as `GenericListener`.  This was created like this for Java 5.0, when Generics was introduced, to provide backwards compatibility with pre-generics code.

Comment: Isn't it a bit strange, then, that the last example runs just fine?

`GenericListener<Integer> integerListener = this::integerReceived;
        new CallbackProducer().addIntegerListener(integerListener);`

Also, using the old method of an anonymous class works fine even though the listener's type parameter is specified an Integer.